# Is there a tools which predicts and corrects the mouse trajectory in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, mouse, extension

I have just switched from Unity 7 to Ubuntu GNOME (3.20), and like every time I have changed my operyting system in the past, I had a long time adapting myself to the mouse movements and the system button positions. Changing the mouse's speed doesn't help so much, so I came to an idea :

Is there actually a tools which predicts where the mouse is moving to, adapting the trajectory to a certain degree ?

It would not be meant for every single link or button inside an app, but simply for some system buttons, like the ones which close the windows, or the system tabs. If I came to the idea so quickly, I'm sure, someboy already thought about it.

Does it exist ? Would it be efficient ?

Thanks to you for answering me :)

Comment: I am confused about what you are actually looking for. How can a mouse predict what you are aiming at?

Comment: Sorry - I mean, for instance, if I move my mouse in direction of a system button like close or minimise, or a tab, but the trajectory isn't perfect (for example, the mouse is going to stop a few pixels apart from it), its trajectory could be optimised in order to stop exactly on it. Of course only if it is obvious enough that the mouse wasn't going to another anchor... It would only be supposed to be a little help to the mouse usage. That is  what I actually meant.